# How to update property bound to a textbox?

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, mvvm, focus

I have a string property bound to a textbox. On the same screen there are 2 buttons in the App bar, one of the being the accept button. Now if I start typing in the textbox and hit the accept button without unfocusing the textbox, when I access the property in my viewmodel its says its empty. But if I tap outside the textbox and it loses focus, the property is updated.

Is there a way to manually update the binding so that it can accurately show what was typed in the textbox?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've handled that by using the TextBox Text property directly.

```
    private void SaveButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (NameTextBox.Text == _originalName) return;

        Model.Name = NameTextBox.Text;
        Model.Save();

        if(NavigationService.CanGoBack) NavigationService.GoBack();
    }
```

Even tho my TextBox is bound to the Name property. This ensures that it will always be up-to-date

Comment: Ha! That was simple. Thanks for the tip.

Answer (score 0):

Try using a behavior from [here](http://www.dotnetcurry.com/ShowArticle.aspx?ID=737). It would be much more MVVM lie that in previous answer.